# "ImportError: cannot import name PathCompleter" when running PtPython

Tags: python, 18.10, ipython

I wanted to use ptipython to run a web driver.

So I first installed iPython using `pip install ipython`, and ptipython in the same way. I had some problems with prompt-toolkit versions, but somehow I solved them.

Now when I run ipython it starts with no problems, but when I run ptipython this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ptipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ptpython/entry_points/run_ptipython.py", line 41, in run
    from ptpython.ipython import embed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ptpython/ipython.py", line 14, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.completion import PathCompleter, WordCompleter
ImportError: cannot import name PathCompleter
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You want me to uninstall them both , then reinstall ?

Comment: I've tried myself to reinstall it a couple times before, and still the same stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need ptipython which is causing the error message, only ptpython. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo pip uninstall ptipython ipython  
sudo apt install ipython
python -m pip install --user ptpython
```

Alternatively you could do this with Python 3 instead of Python 2.7 by installing python3-ipython instead of python-ipython or you could install both ipython packages alongside each other with `sudo apt install python-ipython python3-ipython`

Comment: Yeah, I did a bit of you help and some research I found out that I acctually do not need ptipython, to run the webdriver and can use only ipython. Thanks for you help

Comment: Try using it for a while and if you get an error message upload the code to a pastebin website and provide a link to it in a comment, so I can try running the same code. The easy way to fix this problem is to run the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove it from my system pip with `sudo pip uninstall ptpython` and install it only in the virtualenv I was using. Then the error went away for me.